# Font PDF417 display in Report builder but not PDF document which reports create

Tags: oracle, fonts, oraclereports

When I migrate RDF report which is create in Reports6i to Reports12c in Report builder 12c I can see all barcode fonts which we use in this report, but when start this report -> report create PDF document from Oracle Forms I can't see this barcode fonts. At this time we use Code PDF417 (PDF417.TTF) as 2Dbarcode and IDAutomationC128M (IDAutomationC128M.ttf)

Answer (score 0):

Reports 6i is a client-server technology. You copied .REP files to each client and users ran their own copies of reports, using fonts installed on their own computers.

Reports 12c runs on web (I guess you use Weblogic server) which means that reports' executables are stored on the server, while users just see the result - nothing is installed on their own computers. Therefore, I guess that font - that is missing in your 12c reports - isn't installed on the server. If that's so, contact your administrators and ask them to install the font.

Comment: All fonts is in Windows\fonts director on server. In registry under … Oracle software Key  I have string …  REPORTS_PATH Where I added Windows\Fonts as new part of predefine string all install fonts ar TTF fonts.  I didn’t change UIFONT.ALI. Is it OK ? I use RDF in Reports12c not REP and in Reports12c - Report builder I can see this fonts but in Web browser and PDF document which reports create fonts is OLD Bookman ?!?